# Flying Bloodthirsty Lampshades

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I vaguely remember an old black and white movie with things that looked like lampshades. The lampshades would  settle on a persons head and they would start bleeding and die. Anybody know the movie?

Comment: Hi, welcome to SF&F!  How long ago did you see the movie?  On TV or in a theatre?

Comment: TV and I was a child. I'm 60 now. So around 50 years ago.

Comment: There was a Benny Hill episode in which the furniture ATTACKED!

Comment: I definitely thought this was going to be a [TVTropes reference](https://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/LampshadeHanging).

Answer (score 39):

## "[Not of this Earth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_of_This_Earth_%281957_film%29)" (1957)

Roger Corman's [1957 film](https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0050778/) included, among other things, a flying alien shaped like a lampshade that lands on Dr. Rochelle's head and kills him, with blood pooling out. A fuller synopsis may be found [on Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Not_of_This_Earth_%281957_film%29).

[image: Not of this Earth]

Comment: Awesome special effects.

Comment: That's the world's tiniest gif. I feel like I'm gonna break it by accident.

Comment: Seems like a prototype for what would become the xenomorph's egg layer

Comment: @Valorum - I tried larger dimensions first, but had to play around for a while with tradeoffs of size, dithering, bit depth, and noise to get it under SE's 2 MiB image limit. (Heh, I remember when, back during belt-onion days, a 2 MiB GIF would have seemed enormous, and  [a GiF of these approximate dimensions](https://web.archive.org/web/20050712054846/http://multilockon.hp.infoseek.co.jp/kabe.gif) could be considered remarkable solely for other reasons.) Btw, your edit actually did break 2 links by accident. :P (IMDB link got malformed, and WP link got hidden entirely -- I've fixed both.)

Comment: What is this, a gif for ants?

Comment: @Valorum - No, that would be [this GIF](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/e/eb/Leafcutter_ants.gif). More seriously, SE does [allow](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/25051/resizing-an-image-in-a-post) embedding it as <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaCZv.gif" width="640" height="356" alt="Not of this Earth (1957) excerpt">, but I'm not sure that'd be an improvement...

Comment: That's a gif *of* ants. I'm pretty sure that other ants would hate it.

Comment: You'd be surprised. I hear their version of ["Dirty Jobs"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dirty_Jobs) is really popular. Admittedly, the show's biggest draw for them is the literal dirt, though, not the impressive feats of labor.