# Mid-50s sci-fi movie in which one of the creatures flutters through the air and lands on victims heads and encloses it with its body

Tags: story-identification, movie

Does anyone know the name of a movie in which one of the creatures flutters through the air and lands on victims heads and encloses it with its body?

Comment: @closevoters - I'm confused as to why this is VTC'ed. Information please?

Comment: Sure it was a movie and not an Outer Limits episode.  Wait a minute, I think the movie "Not of this Earth" had a scene like that.

Comment: A bit later than the 50's, but given the vagueness of the question, are you thinking of these guys from Beastmaster: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-SegQXGEGKw?

Comment: The *encloses it with its body* reminds me of the Creeper from https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jeepers_Creepers_2

Comment: Not sure whether *The Vaults of Yoh-Vombis* (https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/172299/pulp-era-sci-fi-horror-story) was ever made into a movie, but the creature you describe sounds like the creatures in that story.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/208823/flying-bloodthirsty-lampshades

Comment: Hello Leona, do you remember anything else about the movie? When did you see it? Perhaps any of the actors? Perhaps you can [edit] that in. As it stands, it's a bit little to go on. We have [a list of suggestions](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/a/9337/19561) that might help jog your memory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

OK, I've quick searched "Not of this Earth".  It's on YouTube and the scene in question starts at 59:30.

Comment: reminds me of Alien's face hugger and also the Creeper's "frills."

Comment: My answer is 50's era.  Not sure about "The Creeper".  (The only Creeper I know was the 60's Ditko Comic.

Comment: i mean the creature looks like the membraneous frills of The Creeper from Jeepers Creepers.

Comment: Nice work! I had the mental image of the scene in the film, but couldn't locate it.

Comment: In case that Youtube video goes down, the relevant scene [can be viewed in GIF form in a previous answer I contributed](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/a/208831/85401).

Comment: Not sure if Emsley Wyatt or Shoover posted "Not of this Earth," but whoever did is absolutely correct!  Now my friend can finally sleep at night.  Thank you everyone.